# EntityFieldQueryException when saving node

Tags: entities, nodes

I have created a node type which I want to use to store events in. I can create new nodes of this type with no problems, but when I want to edit and save a existing node, I get this error:

[image]

In english, this means "Unknown field:". However, a field with this name isn't even defined in my node type:

[image]

Full size image here: http://d.pr/i/8V36

Do you have any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: I added a field "field_event" of the type "Entity Reference" and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I would check and see if the field (field_event) exists. Go to Fields list under reports (admin/reports/fields). You can also check the "field_config" table directly and see if the field exists.

Comment: There is no such field listed under admin/reports/fields, nor in the MySQL table.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever have a field_event on your site, do you know? It's likely that this error is caused by a previous field, that was improperly deleted.